# Windows Gadgets: Testing environment?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, windows-desktop-gadgets

Is there anything that provides a console, error logging, etc. for testing Windows Gadgets? I've searched but I'm unable to find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and easy start is to just use any web developing toolkit. I found out myself that for developing simple Windows Gadgets, Notepad++ and Firefox with its Web Developer toolbar was more than enough. You can implement all the business logic and just test the results in a browser. Actually starting it as a Gadget was only needed to fine-tune some graphical glitches that always occur because of different browsers still interpreting CSS a little differently.
Firefox has some nice tools for debugging Javascript.

Comment: however, the problem is the the Network posts.
in firefox it shows the posts and give the required result. but that required result do not work in gadget it self.
how can i monitor the network posts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebug lite for IE (i.e put a script tag and include the latest firebug lite version).It does look a bit crude but it works nonetheless and its seamless integration for testing.

http://getfirebug.com/lite/ie.html

Though your gadget might seem a bit mutilated when using it.
:)